# Scriban template split string

Tags: scriban

I have a pipe-separated string

```
www.test.com | www.test1.com
```

I want to get just the first string before the pipe that is `www.test.com`.

How can I do this in the scriban template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scriban has a split function on strings: https://github.com/scriban/scriban/blob/master/doc/builtins.md#stringsplit

> `string.split <text> <match>`
>
> The split function takes on a substring as a parameter. The substring is used as a
> delimiter to divide a string into an array. You can output different parts of an
> array using array functions.

Also check the whitespace control if needed (I do see spaces around your pipes): https://github.com/scriban/scriban/blob/master/doc/language.md#14-whitespace-control

> - The greedy mode using the character - (e.g {{- or -}}), removes any whitespace, including newlines
> - The non greedy mode using the character ~
>
>   - Using a {{~ will remove any whitespace before but will stop on the first newline without including it
>   - Using a ~}} will remove any whitespace after including the first newline but will stop after

Working with arrays is explained at https://github.com/scriban/scriban/blob/master/doc/builtins.md#array-functions.
You could use `array.first <list>` to get the first element.

**Update**

Try:
`{{ i_item.URLList | string.split "|" | array.first }}`

That should do it..

Comment: i tried the following. I can get the urls in the list but cannot get the first url from array   
 {{ for urls in i_item.URLList | string.split ' ' ~}}
{{ end }}
{{ urls }}
 {{ urls | array.first }}

Comment: Why are you using a for loop? You don't have to loop through your split items..

Comment: because the field i_item.URLList has values like www.test.com | www.test1.com
. So first I need to convert it into the array and then get the first array element?

Comment: Added to the answer.. should work like that (as Alina also mentioned)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use the string split (by '|') function that will get you the array: [www.test.com, www.test1.com]. Then you can read first element of the array using array first  function.
Example:

```
{{ for word in "Hi, how are you today?" | string.split ' ' ~}}
{{ word }}
{{ end ~}}
```

output

```
Hi,

how

are

you

today?
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. How can I read the first element?

Comment: example: {{ [4, 5, 6] | array.first }}

Comment: i tried the following. I can get the urls in the list but cannot get the first url from array   
 {{ for urls in i_item.URLList | string.split ' ' ~}}
{{ end }}
{{ urls }}
 {{ urls | array.first }}

Comment: can you try: {{ "url1|url2" | string.split '|' | array.first }} where "url1|url2" is i_item.URLList . You can test code here: https://scribanonline.azurewebsites.net/